# Windows 7 Raid - Drives can't see each other

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, raid-0

I'm trying to stripe two drives using the disk management tool. Both partitions give me the option to stripe them but when I use the wizard the other drive doesn't show up to allow me to raid to it!
Both drives have partitions on them at the moment, but I was under the impression that this will make a raid partition rather than a drive. Correct?

Comment: You want one partition and one free space.

Comment: Both drives have used partitions. Disk0 has c: with a 518gb of unused space. Disk1 Has a d: and 506gb of unused space.

Comment: That won't work. Unused space is not useful for striping another partition. You need free space, not part of any filesystem.

Comment: Ah, I mean free space. As in not partitioned.